What basic properties can we use to show that every ring $A$ is a flat module over itself?
What properties can we use to prove that a ring $A$ is a flat module over itself?
I know that if $0 \to E' \to E$ is an injection of $A$-modules, then: $A \otimes E'$ is additively generated by $A$-linear combinations of elements of the form $1\otimes e'$ where $e' \in E'$.  This is because in the tensor product we have that $a\otimes e' = a(1\otimes e')$.  But furthermore, that equals $1\otimes ae'$.  So maybe each element is just a sum of $1\otimes e'$'s.  However, I have assumed that $A$ is unital!
So I'm really not sure how to proceed.  This is listed on page 613 of Lang and proof left to the reader.

$A\otimes_A E\cong E$. $A\otimes_A(-)$ is isomorphic to the identity functor, which is obviously exact, so $A$ is flat. Perhaps, $A$ should be unital. But all rings should be unital!

I see, so $e \mapsto 1\otimes e$ is the isomorphism (no need for summing as shown in my post), and so $A \otimes_A$ is isomorphic naturally with the identity functor. Isomorphism of functors preserves exactness.  Thanks!  Should I delete? @FShrike

Eh, you don't have to. Someone is bound to google this exact question in the future! It's surely been googled hundreds of times

By the way, I should acknowledge that off the top of my head I don't know the answer in case $A$ is nonunital. All I meant by my comment is that, of course rings should be defined as unital (and associative, and in some contexts as commutative); whether all rngs are flat over themselves, I don't know. I haven't thought about it

Let $M$ be an $A$-module. The map $A\times M\to M$ sending $(a,m)\mapsto am$ factors through the tensor product as a map $A\otimes_AM\to M$ sending $a\otimes m\mapsto am$. Then, the map $M\to A\otimes_AM$ sending $m\mapsto 1\otimes m$ is a two-sided inverse of the first map. Hence, $A\otimes_AM\cong M$ for any $A$-module $M$. Hence, $A\otimes_A(-)$ is the identity functor on $A$-modules, hence exact.
Hope this helps. :)
